# horizon ingest the historical data

Tags: stellar-core, horizon, catchup

I'm running a new horizon v1.2 with `ingest=true`. It is connected to the stellar core with `CATCHUP_COMPELTE` enabled. (the status of the core is catching up 5%)

My question is what is the command to run the horizon to ingest all of the historical data? 
I used `horizon serve` the same as the previous versions of the horizon but doesn't ingest the old data.

I used `horizon db reingest 1 29599089` and I get this error `time="2020-05-11T14:19:55.542Z" level=error msg="Error in ingestion state machine" current_state="reingestHistoryRange(fromLedger=1, toLedger=29599089, force=false)" error="error processing ledger sequence=1: Error creating ledger reader: ledger not found" next_state=stop pid=1 service=expingest`

Answer (score 1):

> My question is what is the command to run the horizon to ingest all of the historical data? I used `horizon serve` the same as the previous versions of the horizon but doesn't ingest the old data.

Currently, Horizon starts ingesting ledgers starting at the latest checkpoint and it won't start until this ledger is present in Stellar-Core.

> `time="2020-05-11T14:19:55.542Z" level=error msg="Error in ingestion state machine" current_state="reingestHistoryRange(fromLedger=1, toLedger=29599089, force=false)" error="error processing ledger sequence=1: Error creating ledger reader: ledger not found" next_state=stop pid=1 service=expingest`

This error means that Horizon tried to ingest ledger 1 but it was not found in Stellar-Core database. You can try running:

```sql
select min(ledgerseq), max(ledgerseq) from ledgerheaders;
```

in Stellar-Core database to understand what's the first and the last ledger in it's DB (beware: [gaps are possible](https://www.stellar.org/developers/software/known-issues.html#gaps-detected)).

It's possible that you have [`AUTOMATIC_MAINTENANCE_COUNT`](https://github.com/stellar/stellar-core/blob/master/docs/stellar-core_example.cfg#L296-L302) set in your Stellar-Core config so it returns older ledgers from time to time.

Comment: thank you Bartek Nowotarski.
both core and horizon are using a new DB since a few hours ago. Perhaps that the reason that ledger 1 still doesn't exist in the core DB.

Comment: what would be the best way to run a new horizon and core together? @Bartek Nowotarski

I was wondering if this works: 
1. core catchup current/max
2. stop the core and run horizon db reingest 1 current
3. run both horizon and core